# How to append list of numerous types to single string (python)

Tags: python, string, list

If I have a list as such:

```
arr = [
         ["Hi ", "My ", "Name "],
         ["Is ", "Sally. ", "Born "],
         [3, 13, 2010]  
]
```

How would you get that in a single string that states

```
H, My Name Is Sally. Born 3 13 2010
```

Is there a simpler way than

```
example = ""
for x in range(len(arr)): 
    for j in range(len(arr[x])):
        example = example + str(arr[x][j])
print (example)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `' '.join`:

```
myList = [
     ["Hi ", "My ", "Name "],
     ["Is ", "Sally. ", "Born "],
     [3, 13, 2010]  
] 

sentence = ''.join(str(i)+[' ', ''][type(i) == str] for b in myList for i in b)[:-1]
```

Output:

```
'Hi My Name Is Sally. Born 3 13 2010'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.chain`:

```
import itertools as it
''.join(map(str, it.chain(*arr)))
```

**EDIT:**

I just noticed OP wants space between numbers. So it should be:

```
''.join(map(lambda s: s if isinstance(s, str) else str(s)+' ', it.chain(*arr))).rstrip()
```

Comment: Hi liliscent, thanks for the update. Is this just a matter of esthetic and 'religion' (functional programming vs imperative(?)) or is that actual faster? Maybe it is out of scope but I would appreciate it if you could point me in a direction. Thanks!

Comment: @YannicHamann Not for performance reason, though `itertools` module is implemented directly in C([see here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c)). Usually this style will be more readable than a C-style loop, but not always. Besides readability, when writing in this style, library functions take care of corner cases automatically. C-style code might be more error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [liliscent's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8605791/liliscent) answer, here is the solution with white spaces after the integer to string conversion:

```
import itertools as it

''.join([el if isinstance(el, str) else str(el) + ' ' for el in it.chain(*arr)]).rstrip()
```

Answer (score 0):

If put in one line:

```
res = " ".join(map(lambda lst: " ".join(map(lambda i: str(i).strip(), lst)), myList))
```

Break down:

The last list contains only integer numbers. If converted to string, they will not have an extra white space at the back like the previous lists.

Hence, for each of the three sub-lists I do:
`map(lambda i: str(i).strip(), lst)`, where the `strip()` function is to remove the white space in front and behind a string, similar to the `trim()` function in java.

Then the `" ".join()` function is to join all values in a **list of strings** and become a new string where elements in the original list is separated by `" "`.

Hence map each of the three sub-lists into string values, then join again.